# "data-migration" and "migrate" tags as synonym of "migration"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There were questions using [data-migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration) and [migrate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate), and I removed the tags from those questions.

In the case the tags keep being used, would making them synonym of [migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration) make sense?
How much times should those tags be used, before to be considered candidates for synonyms of [migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migration)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure about this one, [migrate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate) refers specifically to the migrate module which serves the purpose of data migration but isn't the only tool useful for achieving said migration. I think it's necessary to keep this tag for questions about this module.
[data-migration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-migration) will cover much broader topics than [migrate](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/migrate).

Comment: Keeping two tags that are too similar causes, IMO, just confusion about which one to use. The purpose of the Migrate module is mainly to help migration; having a tag for the Migrate module, and one for  migrations is like having [tag:feeds] for the Feeds module, and [tag:rss] for feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Why should these be synonyms? We generally only want to create synonyms when there is a *demonstrated need*, e.g. people are asking questions with those tags.

Doing it speculatively would lead to a lot of useless mind-reading synonyms...

Comment: When I asked this question there were questions tagged with one of those tags, otherwise I would not have asked the question.